# to have one table or split into two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to download some daily financial prices for approx 10,000 securities. The prices will start from 1980 until today. I have to download the prices in USD and in their local currency.

My question is whether to have two tables like below, one for the USD prices and the other for the local currency. Or should I add a field, Currency nvarchar(3) to my table below. Which is the better practise?

```
   datePrice date
   id   nvarchar(11)
   price float
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your definition correctly, I'd just have one table. Something like `CREATE TABLE SecurityPrice (id nvarchar(11), PriceDate date, LocalPrice decimal(12,2), USDPrice decimal(12,2));` There's no need to store in two different tables, you'd end up duplicating the vast majority of the data.

Comment: The important question is - at some point might you have a third currency?

Comment: Are you talking of database tables or table variables? For database tables I definitely would use only one table with Id, Date and Currency as PK.

Comment: @Larnu of course! Sorry just realise how stupid I was being

Comment: @Jamiec good point, we will not be having a third currency

Comment: Before you do anything, you need to really think about the term "local price". Your description already assumes a particular POV. Is that safe? Typically a system that supports multiple currencies (an over-simplification) allows the user to determine what is local vs. what is base. Using floating point might also be a bad idea.

Comment: create a new table with exchange rates and join with that table if you need the price in another currency. But also add dates in that table, so you now what the exchange rate for that date was. This way there is no need to keep the foreign currency in this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go with 2 tables - thats just a bad solution all round.

I'd also suggest adding a `varchar(3)` field is also a bad solution, as you'll end up with a lot of duplication.

If you're absolutely sure you'll only ever have 2 currencies then 2 fields in your one table will suffice (usdPrice, localPrice).

However the more scalable solution is a security table (Id/Other info) and a reference table which stores a foreign key back to the securityId, a foreign key to the currencyId, the date and the price